# Conflicting unilateral and bilateral tests. How to proceed?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose I have $H_0: \beta = 0$ vs $H_1: \beta \neq 0$. My data tells me that I don't reject the null, with a p-value of approximately 0.06.

Then out of curiosity, since by the scientific theory one would expect $\beta<0$, I test $H_0: \beta \geq 0$ vs $H_1: \beta < 0$, and the data says that we should reject the null, with a p-value of 0.03...

I get the reason why we're having these two different conclusions has to do with the different quantiles we're using.

However, how should I conclude in this situation?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407009/conflicting-unilateral-and-bilateral-tests-which-one-should-i-base-myself-on

Comment: Ideally, you should choose a test before you do your experiment, and stick with it, rather than going "test-shopping".  Given any data set and a sufficiently rich collection of different possible tests, it s almost certain that you can find one that lets you reject the null hypothesis, even if the null hypothesis happens to be true.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for your comment ;)